# Cauchy sequences are bounded in every metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

A few days laid out an example, and asked for help, and @ shadow10 replied, his answer the question of can I find the

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879662/every-Cauchy-sequence-is-bounded

but please someone help me in relation to this question:
*as would seem replies @ shadow10 in a space of arbitrary metric.*

I know only that we should place absolute value $d (x, y)$.

Please help. Previously thank you

Comment: You can replace $|x_n-x_m|$ by $d(x_n,x_m)$ in the proof.

Comment: yes, but please help me, you have ready solution, then you can only make changes if you think, because I do not understand how to make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X,d)$ a metric space and $(x_n)_n$ a Cauchy sequence, and $a\in X$.
$\epsilon=1$. There is a $N$ such that $\forall m,n\ge N$
$$d(x_m,x_n)<1$$
by triangular inequality we have  $d(x_n,a)\leq d(x_n,x_N)+d(x_N,a)$, then for $n\geq N$ we obtain $d(x_n,a)\leq 1+d(x_N,a)=C$.

Then If we take $M=\max\{d(x_0,a),\dots,d(x_{N-1},a),C\}$.
Then $d(x_n,a)\le M\;\forall\,n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @ Hamou Thanks, sir